# MYSQL - Selecting one different value, and one the same from same table

Tags: mysql

I have one table, with different dates, and similar other parameters.  It looks likes this :

```
ID - Date - Domain Name
1 ! 02-20-2013 ! google.com
2 ! 02-20-2013 ! yahoo.com
3 ! 02-20-2013 ! whoknows.com
4 ! 02-20-2013 ! NULL
5 ! 04-25-2013 ! yahoo.com
6 ! 04-25-2013 ! something.com
7 ! 04-25-2013 ! google.com
8 ! 04-25-2013 ! NULL
9 ! 04-25-2013 ! google.com
```

I want to run a query that will find the DOMAIN NAME values that were in 02-20-2013 that are now also showing in 04-25-2013 (not NULL or empty values ofcourse)

So the output would be :

```
5 ! 04-25-2013 ! yahoo.com
7 ! 04-25-2013 ! google.com
9 ! 04-25-2013 ! google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to join the table to itself.

```
SELECT t2.* FROM MyTable t1 
  JOIN MyTable t2 
    ON t1.`Domain Name` = t2.`Domain Name`
 WHERE t1.date = '2013-02-20'
   AND t2.date = '2013-04-25'
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbcac/12)

Note that "04-25-2013" isn't a standard date format - you may want to use "2013-04-25".

Comment: Yes... Join. He asked for domains present on both dates, not either date.

Comment: wtf you're right :D i misunderstood the question cause of my bad english pfff ahah thanks

Comment: @SamDufel - Your query is perfect. I just updated as per OP's requirement. Sorry for that.

Comment: @hims056 - thanks, I'm on an iPad at the moment and typing is a little tedious.

Comment: This Query can catch empty string '', you need to add case that 'Domain Name' not equal to empty string ...

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbcac/14)**

```
SELECT m1.* 
FROM mytable m1
WHERE m1.date = '2013-04-25' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 0
            FROM mytable m2
            WHERE m2.`Domain Name` = m1.`Domain Name`
            AND m2.`Domain Name` is not null
            AND m2.`Domain Name` != ''
            AND m2.date = '2013-02-20')
```

Result:

```
| ID |                         DATE | DOMAIN NAME |
---------------------------------------------------
|  5 | April, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   yahoo.com |
|  7 | April, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  google.com |
|  9 | April, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  google.com |
```